# Volume below the cone $z=2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for $x^2+y^2\leq4$

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, volume

For $x^2+y^2=4$,
$$z=2\sqrt{4}\Rightarrow z=4$$
Since the radius of the basis is $2$, then the volume of the cone is
$$V=\frac{\pi\cdot2^2\cdot4}{3}\Rightarrow V=\frac{16\pi}{3}$$

However, using double integral and polar coordinates, I get
$$V=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2} 2r^2 dr d\theta=\frac{32\pi}{3}$$

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're integrating the wrong or the opposite volume. Instead of integrating the volume inside the cone, you're integrating the volume outside the cone. This corresponds to the fact that a cone has $\frac{1}{3}$ of the volume of a cylinder with same base and height.

Comment: But shouldn't be the volume given by $\iint_{R} f(x,y)dA$?

Comment: Your choice of function is wrong. The correct function to integrate is $4-2r^2$. Can you see why?

Comment: @EemilWallin He says "Volume below the cone" in  the title, which should correspond to the result of the integral. So the reason is, he shouldn't expect it to equal the volume of the cone itself.

Comment: The base of cone is up on plane $z=4$, not on $z=0$, so answer is correct - the integral calculates volume outside of cone, so, it's twice more, then cone itself.